# collating values on a single row in R dataframe dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data of student exam points:

```
     MAPPING PupilMatchingRefAnonymous POINTS 
1    PHYS        1                      60  
2    COMP        1                      40  
3    ENGL        1                      20  
4    MATH        1                      80
```

I want to add each student's maths and english scores to each of their exams for easy comparison:

```
  MAPPING PupilMatchingRefAnonymous POINTS  MATH    ENGL
1    PHYS        1                      60  80      20
2    COMP        1                      40  80      20
3    ENGL        1                      20  80      20
4    MATH        1                      80  80      20
```

I've tried the following code, but no luck:

```
comResults %>%
    select(MAPPING, PupilMatchingRefAnonymous, POINTS) %>%
    group_by(PupilMatchingRefAnonymous) %>% 
    mutate(MATH=ifelse(MAPPING=="MATH", POINTS, NA))

  Error: incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector
```

Any idea what I should attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to transpose it from long form to wide form, right?

If so, try this:

```
library(tidyr)
new.df <- comResults %>%
  spread(MAPPING, POINTS)
```

That will make 1 student be 1 row with all of their academic info in the same row.  I know you wanted only Math and English but maybe this code will get you on the right track.

Comment: I thought spread was part of `dplyr` but I could be wrong. Honestly, I just load `dplyr` and `tidyr` together anyway.  I added `tidyr` to my answer for clarification.

Edit: yep I misread the ?spread() info from R.  It's definitely `tidyr`

Answer (score 3):

Using base, this seem to be pretty straight forward

```
df[as.character(df$MAPPING)] <- rep(df$POINTS, each = nrow(df))
df
#   MAPPING PupilMatchingRefAnonymous POINTS PHYS COMP ENGL MATH
# 1    PHYS                         1     60   60   40   20   80
# 2    COMP                         1     40   60   40   20   80
# 3    ENGL                         1     20   60   40   20   80
# 4    MATH                         1     80   60   40   20   80
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how dplyr handles merges but this base-R solution would produce the result (less the names, whch ought to be fairly simple to fix:)

```
merge(merge(dat, dat[dat$MAPPING=="MATH", -1], by='PupilMatchingRefAnonymous'),
      dat[dat$MAPPING=="ENGL", -1] , by='PupilMatchingRefAnonymous')
#--------
  PupilMatchingRefAnonymous MAPPING POINTS.x POINTS.y POINTS
1                         1    PHYS       60       80     20
2                         1    COMP       40       80     20
3                         1    ENGL       20       80     20
4                         1    MATH       80       80     20
```

Here's a two student dataset for further testing:

```
 dput(dat)
structure(list(MAPPING = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("COMP", "ENGL", "MATH", "PHYS"), class = "factor"), 
    PupilMatchingRefAnonymous = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), POINTS = c(60L, 40L, 20L, 80L, 20L, 40L, 0L, 80L)), .Names = c("MAPPING", 
"PupilMatchingRefAnonymous", "POINTS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: This doesn't generalize. You will need to do this for each row

Comment: @David: I don't understand. You are saying that in cases of more than one value for PupilMatchingRefAnonymous, that the merge would occur improperly?

Comment: I'm saying that you explicitly naming `dat$MAPPING=="ENGL"`, `dat$MAPPING=="MATH"`, etc. while merging. This means that you will need to explicitly name *every* value of the `MAPPING` variable in order to create all the columns. Unless you have a way to generalize this?

Comment: Ah. I've no argument with the notion that yours appeared superior with one student. With two students it creates excessive columns.